# Ordinal properties: if $\lambda<\kappa$ then $\lambda\cap\kappa<\kappa$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

How can I show that,

if $\lambda$ and $\kappa$ are two ordinals (limit or successors) and if $\lambda < \kappa$,

then $\lambda\cap\kappa<\kappa$

Comment: What exactly you mean by $A\cap B$ for ordinals? For example if you define ordinals as equivalence classes then this doesn't make much sense. Anyway there's always an embedding $i:A\cap B\to B$, $i(x)=x$ that preserves an order (I assume that both $A$, $B$ share ordering, i.e. they are subsets of some well ordered set). Hence always $A\cap B < B$ (no mattter how $A$ and $B$ are related).

Comment: There is nothing precise written about intersection, which is why I suppose just the standard notion which corresponds to those and only those elements which are contained in both of the ordinals.

Comment: Freakish : ordinals aren't usually defined as equivalence classes; I think here the definition used is that of a transitive set well ordered by $\in$.

Comment: @Eurydice : $\lambda\in\kappa$, since $\kappa$ is an ordinal this implies $\lambda\subset \kappa$. Therefore...

Comment: isn't $\lambda\cap\kappa=\lambda$???, since $\forall \xi,\xi<\lambda\iff\xi<\lambda<\kappa$

Comment: Yep, if we define ordinals as transitive sets, then this is trivial as @JulioMaldonadoHenríquez notes.